# Is there any way to tell if a Pokemon is about to run away or is prone to running away?

Tags: pokemon-go

Over the last few days I've had a few Pokemon run away  while I was trying to catch them. Sometimes a Pokemon runs away after a few tries while others go for much longer. I have berries now so I can try to keep around longer, but I don't know if and when a Pokemon will run away.

Is there a a way to tell when Pokemon are about to run away or are more likely to run away?

Comment: the odds of it running go up after failed attempts, but I don't think there are any visual queues except maybe it jumping around more.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pokemon give no visual indication of being about to run away.

However, Pokemon such as Abra are (still) almost guaranteed to run following a failed capture attempt. The chance any given Pokemon will run away on the first throw (without any sort of modifier) is given in the [`BaseFleeRate` variable](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/077d6dea82d58b8febde54ae9729b1bf) from the decoded ProtoBuf file.

Additionally, Pokemon with orange or red rings have a higher initial chance of running away. All Pokemon will run after enough turns have progressed, as the chance of a run increases each unsuccessful turn.

Comment: Are there any deeper statics on what the base chance is with orange or red rings that they will run away?

Comment: @Dom If there are, I haven't been able to find any. It seems to be dependent on CP though.

Comment: @KazWolfe source please. What are you basing `chance of a run increases each unsuccessful turn` on?

Comment: @ton.yeung https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/4u88we/are_we_sure_running_away_occurs_normally/d5nzeyw, personal experience, and confirmation from basically everyone I know who plays it.

Comment: Then I'll have to respectfully disagree. Without something more definitive, this should not be marked an answer. Is it possible that its true? Yes. Is it possible that its not true? Also Yes. I'm leaning towards not true considering there are base flee and catch rates and difference between level and cp modifies these rates. That means a harder to catch pokemon will have more chances to flee, especially if they have a higher base flee rate.

Comment: @ton.yeung If you find conflicting definitive evidence to my answer, feel free to post it and I will edit it accordingly. Until then, I (and the OP) feel it to be accurate, therefore it will stay. My goal is not to intentionally spread misinformation here.

Comment: Sorry if  it sounded that way. Re-reading the OP's post and your answer, I agree that the answer is correct, as it **does** address the OP's question on whether or not there is an indication that a pokemon will flee.

Comment: The thing that bothers me is the way the last sentence is phrased, as its true the more times a pokemon pops out of a ball, the higher the chance of the a pokemon fleeing. However, the calculation for the chance of a pokemon fleeing is not proven to be dependent on the number of times it pops out of the pokeball. The reason why the chances of a pokemon fleeing are higher is because failing to catch a pokemon gives the pokemon the chance of "deciding" to flee. The reason why this seemingly minor detail bothers me is because of a rumor that if you run from the pokemon and try again, it resets.

Comment: Though this answer is outdated, the last part of "Additionally, Pokemon with orange or red rings have a higher initial chance of running away." is incorrect. Pokemon with lower catch rates (and subsequently being more likely to have red or orange circles) generally also have lower flee rates, not higher. For example, often when Pokemon evolve, both their flee and capture rates decrease. My source: https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4tc929/pokemon_catch_flee_rates_table_and_analysis/

Answer (score 1):

Every species has a probability of running away. Just look for BaseFleeRate in [the decoded game file](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/077d6dea82d58b8febde54ae9729b1bf). A Pokémon with BaseFleeRate of 0.99 (like Abra) has 99% probability to run away after an unsuccessful throw, whereas a Metapod with BaseFleeRate 0.07 is much more likely to stick around while you waste your PokéBalls perfecting the curve ball.

Answer (score 1):

The current answers are outdated. Now Pokemon Go stops you from throwing Pokeballs or using Berries when a Pokemon is about to run away.

The only way to predict how likely a Pokemon is to run is by its base flee rate, which is set for each Pokemon. As a general but not hard-set rule, rarer and harder to catch Pokemon have *lower* base flee rates, not higher as what Wolfe's answer suggests. [Here's a list of flee rates current as of Gen 3.](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/7ii9jx/all_current_catch_and_flee_rates_with_gen_3/) Note that the flee rates are irrelevant for raid and research Pokemon; only when encountered in the wild.